How can I remove error message Vercel so that project deploys?
I tried to commit a change onto my GitHub and deployment on Vercel but now I keep getting this error message:
RollupError: Could not resolve "../../components/Item" from "src/pages/itemDetails/ItemDetails.jsx" and a general Build Failed Command "CI='' npm run build" exited with 1
Also my commit changes are not taking any effect. Can someone please help?
ItemDetails.jsx:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { IconButton, Box, Button, Tabs, Tab } from '@mui/material';
import FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorderOutlined';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import RemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Remove';
import { shades } from '../../theme.js';
import { addToCart } from '../../state/index.js';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Item from '../../components/Item';
import './ItemDetails.css'
import '../../App.css'

...

Item.jsx:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { IconButton, Box, useTheme, Button } from '@mui/material';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import RemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Remove';
import { shades } from '../theme.js'
import { addToCart } from '../state/index.js';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

Products.jsx:
...
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Item from '../../../components/Item'

...

App.jsx:
import ItemDetails from './pages/ItemDetails/ItemDetails'

...

I would like to mention that this happened right after I tried to create a README.md file on the GitHub website instead of creating in my local directory. Would that have something to do with it?
